# How do you include Service Broker in a VS2010 Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, service-broker, database-project

I'm trying to add my Service Broker queues to my database project and I'm not entirely clear on what is the best way to do this. There are two views available to me, Solution Explorer and Schema View. It seems like the only way to get a Service Broker Queue, along with all of it's associated messages/services/contracts is by adding the Queue in the Solution Explorer view and then adding everything else in the Schema View.

Is this correct? Is there not a unified view for all this? What are the best practices for including Service Broker in a Database Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Queues are visible under the Schema View, they just aren't grouped with the Service Broker section, but instead are located under Schemas -> [SchemaName]-> Queues.

Why they aren't grouped together is completely beyond me.